# Finding $\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{\sin^4(\log x)}{x^2 \log x} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How do we prove that $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^4(\log x)}{x^2 \log x} \mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{625}{17}\right)}{16}$$

I tried substitutions like $\log x=\arcsin t$, but it doesn't seem to work out. Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Let $\log x=t$.

Comment: @Alizter then what should I do?

Comment: Wbhat have you tried? Please edit the question to include additional context, including your attempts and also the context in which you encountered the integral.

Comment: Do you know complex integration?

Comment: @CarlMummert could I do it tomorrow? It is late night here in my country and moreover I'm on a cellphone..

Comment: @Pkwssis: yes, there is no hurry, of course. I apologize if I made it sound urgent.

Comment: @CarlMummert, I think OP already stated he tried $\log x = \arcsin t$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The integral screams for a sub $x=e^u$; the result is

$$\int_0^{\infty} du \, e^{-u} \frac{\sin^4{u}}{u} $$

This is very computable by introducing a parameter and differentiating under the integral.  In this case, consider

$$F(k) = \int_0^{\infty} du \, e^{-k u} \frac{\sin^4{u}}{u} $$

$$F'(k) = -\int_0^{\infty} du \, e^{-k u} \sin^4{u} $$

$F'(k)$ is relatively easy to compute using the fact that $\sin^4{u} = \frac{3}{8}-\frac12 \cos{2 u} + \frac18 \cos{4 u}$, and that

$$\int_0^{\infty} du \, e^{-k u} \cos{m u} =  \frac{k}{k^2+m^2}$$

Thus

$$F'(k) = -\frac{3}{8 k} + \frac12 \frac{k}{k^2+4} - \frac18 \frac{k}{k^2+16} $$

and

$$F(k) = -\frac1{16} \log{\left [  \frac{k^6 (k^2+16)}{(k^2+4)^4} \right ]} + C$$

To evaluate $C$, we must consider $\lim_{k \to \infty} F(k)$ because $F(0)$ represents a non convergent integral.  Because the limit is zero, we must have $C=0$.  The integral we seek is then

$$F(1) = \frac1{16} \log{\frac{625}{17}}$$

Comment: We could also use the laplace transform to evaluate the integral.after the substitution, right?

Comment: @Pkwssis: Well, the Laplace transform is just a name for the integral.  It doesn't really offer a method of evaluating the integral, unless you count looking up in tables.

Answer (score 4):

I propose the following approach:

- Let $t=\dfrac1x$
- Let $u=\ln t$.
- Use the [power-reduction formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula) for $\sin^4x$.
- Employ [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) in conjunction with the linear properties of the integral.
- Express your new integral(s) in terms of $I(k)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-kx}~dx$. You'll have $\displaystyle\int I(k)~dk$, where $I(k)$ will turn out to be a rational function in *k*. Solve it by using the [usual methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).